# Append div with saved record after form submits

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

After my form is submitted, I want to add the saved record to my div which contains all the records - or refresh the div or whatever the best practice is.

I'm not sure at all how to do this, so the code inside my create.js.erb file is just a guess.

Form

```
<%= form_for @comment, remote: "true" do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :chat_id, value: @chat.id %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(creation_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id

  if @comment.save
    respond_to do |format|
     format.js
     format.html
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#comments").append("<%= @chat.comments.last %>");
$('#comment_content').val('').focus();
```

Comments div

```
<ul id="comments">
<% @chat.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <li id="comment-<%= comment.id %>">
    <%= comment.user.name %>
    <%= comment.content %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Start by reading up on the ajax features that Rails has out of the box http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks pretty good to me, but I see a couple of things that might need fixing. I admit to being new-ish at this myself, but I have used Ajax a few times with Rails, so I hope my suggestions are helpful.

**Form**

Replace the string `"true"` with the boolean `true` in `remote: "true"`.

```
<%= form_for @comment, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :chat_id, value: @chat.id %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

Add `{render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript'}` after `format.js`.
Also, if you are going to be using `@chat` in create.js.erb, you need to define it in your `create` action.

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(creation_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id
  @chat = # however you can define your @chat variable, if you decide you need it

  if @comment.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript'}
      format.html
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

**create.js.erb**

As Topher Hunt mentioned, it is probably better to use tags so that new comments are formatted with HTML just like the old ones. Also, if your plan is to append the comment just created, no need to use `@chat.comments.last` - use `@comment` instead. And I believe you don't want to append the entire Ruby object (which is what `$("#comments").append("<%= @chat.comments.last %>");` will do), but just its content and creator's name. Be careful with getting the js file error-free, or the whole thing won't work.

```
var markup = '<li id="comment-<%= @comment.id %>"><%= @comment.user.name %><%= @comment.content %></li>';
$("#comments").append(markup);
$('#comment_content').val('').focus();
```

**Comments div**

This looks fine as-is.

```
<ul id="comments">
  <% @chat.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <li id="comment-<%= comment.id %>">
      <%= comment.user.name %>
      <%= comment.content %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first stab looks good for the most part. If I were approaching this problem (and I do since I use lots of ajax in Rails) I'd try to handle (and troubleshoot) each problem separately as much as possible. For example:

- Is the controller action getting called and executing as expected? Sprinkle `puts` statements around the code and watch the console output to verify.
- Is the controller rendering what you'd expect? Chrome's developer window contains a Network tab that lets you see the path, response codes, and load times of every AJAX request made, and click on any request to see its complete body -- meaning you can use that to inspect the exact Javascript being sent back to and executed by the browser.
- Is the Javascript executing properly? Toss in an `alert("Done!");` at the end of the `create.js.erb` snippet to verify.

When I look at the specifics of your code, the main question I have is "What exactly is the string being appended to `#comments`?" The JS command is

```
$("#comments").append("<%= @chat.comments.last %>");
```

but I'd expect you'd need to append something with full HTML markup, not just plain text. So I'd expect something more like this (also note it's broken into 2 steps for easier readibility):

```
var markup = '<li><%= @chat.comments.last %></li>';
$('#comments').append(markup);
```

And finally, my personal AJAX strategy in Rails so far is to **ignore** most of Rails' AJAX magic and UJS. I almost never use the `remote: true` option; instead I write my own Jquery code (precompiled as part of the asset pipeline) to detect a click, send an ajax request, display feedback on the change, and whatever else. That way all my javascript is neatly organized in `/app/assets`, not scattered around in the view folders, and my controllers return JSON (or sometimes a rendered HTML partial) rather than addng extra JS snippets after the page load. It feels cleaner to me, and I feel more in-control of the page behavior.

Of course, one major disadvantage of this is that I forego Rails' UJS support; any features I write like this will fail rather un-gracefully if the browser doesn't support Javascript.